# Está dando erro na matriz utilizando o laço while

Tags: c

Como faço para a matriz seja rodada com o laço while? Meu professor quer que a matriz seja exibida com o laço while eu só sei fazer com o laço for. Segue exemplo com erros de como eu fiz:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
int inteiros[5][5];
int i = 0, j = 0;

//copia do teclado

while(*inteiros != NULL){       
        scanf("%d", &inteiros[i][j]);

        i++;
        j++;
}




 //imprime como formato de matriz

while(*inteiros != NULL){       


        printf("%d", inteiros[i][j]);

        i++;
        j++;
        printf ("\n"); 

}

printf("\n\n");

    //matriz diagonal principal
while(*inteiros != NULL){       
        scanf("%d", &inteiros[i][j]);

            if(i == j){
                printf( "[%d][%d] : %d. ", i, j, inteiros[i][j] );
            }
        i++;
        j++;
    }


printf("\n");
//matriz inversa
```

}

Comment: qual erro esta ocorrendo?

Comment: C# e C são duas coisas **bem** diferentes.

Comment: Eu sei :/ Coloquei duas tags para chamar mais atenção, mesmo.

Comment: @DotNet na verdade ela não funciona de forma esperada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isto? Apenas mudei o tamanho da matriz para 2x2 para facilitar. 
Verifique se entende!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int inteiros[2][2];

    inteiros[0][0] = 1;
    inteiros[0][1] = 2;
    inteiros[1][0] = 3;
    inteiros[1][1] = 4;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i<2) {
        j = 0;
        while(j<2){
            printf("%d\n",inteiros[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: este código apenas imprime a matriz. o resto é com vc :-)